# Http request isn't accepting space in parameter and throwing ClientProtocolException

Tags: java, api, rest, http

`POST Request : http://ca-dev-auto.cmsvals-dev.com/protected/clients/copyCategory.spr?tagname=Insider New_Theory&category=article`

When this exact request is run with Postman, I am getting the required result with 200 status code. When I execute this webservice via HTTP Post request I got ClientProtocolException because of **space** in tagname value.

I tried **URLEncoder** in which space is replaced by '+' operator, this way I got 500 exception. I also replace '+' operator with '%20' but this way I again start getting ClientProtocolException.
Please suggest me what else can be done.

Comment: Thanks, @Lukas Novicky

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [RedirectStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/RedirectStrategy.html)?
In older versions it was setRedirectHandler.

Comment: Yes, this webservice is using redirectStrategy and I have that logic added in my code. ```HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(LaxRedirectStrategy.INSTANCE)
    .build(); ```